# Full Screen Interstitial HTML5 vs Creative Template

Tags: google-dfp

I have been researching how to best implement an interstitial advertisement that has a black overlay background that covers the entire screen with the advertisement piece placed in the center of the screen.

I have successfully created an interstitial creating a custom creative template however this only supports an image ad.

I am trying to achieve the effect where the background is a black overlay and either a image/video/image+video are all shown within the center of the screen.

Can someone tell me if HTML5 is the way to achieve this effect or if creating a custom creative set using Input variables and javascript is going to work better? I would like to be able to use one creative HTML5 template or custom DFP Creative set to allow the ad to handle an image or video.